# HTML update on slider

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a map that displays when a building got built as you move a slider. I want to be able to display, as HTML text, the number of buildings that got built as the slider moves up and down.

The way the slider reads the building is through the date the building got built. So id need a way to read out the count of buildings built at each point in the slider.

I really have no way to go about this, so any help would be really appreciated.

[The slider code is located here](http://bl.ocks.org/cmdoptesc/fc0e318ce7992bed7ca8)

[Map timeline image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKUj6.jpg)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>D3 Mapping Timeline</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/d3.slider.css"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
<style>

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #525252;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

.land-boundary {
  stroke-width: .3px;
}

.county-boundary {
  stroke: #ddd;
    stroke-width: .3px;
}

.state-boundary {
    stroke-width: .3px;
}

.site {
    stroke-width: .5px;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  fill: rgba(228, 127, 218, 0.54);
    cursor: pointer;
}


div.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
        color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
        font-size: 12px;
    background: rgba(236, 236, 236, 0.85);
    border-radius: 2px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#slider3 {
  margin: 130px 0 -30px 220px;
  width: 500px;
}

#title {
    position: absolute;
    margin: -120px 0 10px 240px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#subtitle {
    position: absolute;
    margin: -80px 0 10px 380px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

#axis1985 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 210px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#axis1990 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 275px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#axis1995 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 355px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}


#axis2000 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 435px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#axis2005 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 515px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#axis2010 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 595px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#axis2015 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px 0 10px 675px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#radio {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 2px 0 0 325px;
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    font-size: 11px;
}

/* The container */
.container {
    display: relative;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    margin: 0px 5px 15px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 10px;
        font-family: 'Roboto';
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default radio button */
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Create a custom radio button */
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the radio button is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the indicator (the dot/circle - hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

/* Show the indicator (dot/circle) when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

/* Style the indicator (dot/circle) */
.container .checkmark:after {
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    width: 4.5px;
    height: 4.5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: white;
}

</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/d3.slider.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="title">
        <h1><b>Timeline Map</b></h1>
        </div>

    <div id="subtitle">
        <h5>Move slider to see goals</h5>
        </div>

        <div id="axis1985">
            <h8></h8>
            </div>

        <div id="axis1990">
            <h8>1990</h8>
            </div>

            <div id="axis1995">
                <h8>1995</h8>
                </div>

                <div id="axis2000">
                    <h8>2000</h8>
                    </div>

                    <div id="axis2005">
                        <h8>2005</h8>
                        </div>

                        <div id="axis2010">
                            <h8>2010</h8>
                            </div>

                            <div id="axis2015">
                                <h8>2015</h8>
                                </div>


    <div id="slider3">
        </div>


<div id = "radio">
        <form>
<label class="container"><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio"> <span class="checkmark"></span>Button 1 </label>
<label class="container"><input type="radio" name="radio"><span class="checkmark"></span>Button 2</label>
<label class="container"><input type="radio" name="radio"><span class="checkmark"></span>Button 3</label>
<label class="container"><input type="radio" name="radio"><span class="checkmark"></span>Button 4</label>
        </form>
    </div>

<script>


var width = 960,
    height = 600;

var mapPath = "data/us.json";

// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(960)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json(mapPath, function(error, us) {
  if (error) return console.error(error);

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "land-boundary");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties, function(a, b) { return a !== b && (a.id / 1000 | 0) === (b.id / 1000 | 0); }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "county-boundary");

  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "state-boundary");


  d3.tsv("data/dataFinal.txt")
    .row(function(d) {
      return {
        permalink: d.permalink,
        lat: parseFloat(d.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(d.lon),
                state: d.state,
                fullAddress: d.fullAddress,
                handlerName: d.handlerName,
        date725: moment(d.date725,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                year725: d.year725
            };
    })
    .get(function(err, rows) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);

      window.site_data = rows;
    });
});

//display the sites using "permalink"
var displaySites = function(data) {
  var sites = svg.selectAll(".site")
      .data(data, function(d) {
        return d.permalink;
      });

  sites.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "site")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return projection([d.lng, d.lat])[0];
                        })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection([d.lng, d.lat])[1];
            })
                 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                 div.transition()
                         .duration(200)
                         .style("opacity", .9);
                 div.html("Handler Name:" + "<br>" + d.handlerName + "<br>" +  "<br>" + "Address:" + "<br>" + d.fullAddress + "<br>")
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                 })
             .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                 div.transition()
                        .duration(200)
                      .style("opacity", 0);
            })
              .attr("r", 1)
              .transition().duration(800)
                .attr("r", 7);

  sites.exit()
    .transition().duration(100)
      .attr("r",0)
      .remove();
};

var minDateYear = moment('1985-12-19', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var maxDateYear = moment('2017-09-29', "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
var secondsInDay = 60 * 60 * 24;

d3.select('#slider3').call(d3.slider()
  //.axis(true).min("1986").max("2017")
    .axis(false).min(minDateYear).max(maxDateYear)
  .on("slide", function(evt, value) {
    var newData = _(site_data).filter( function(site) {
      return site.date725 < value;
    })
     //console.log("New set size ", newData.length);
     //console.log("svg value ", newData);
    displaySites(newData);
  })
);

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but quickly skimming through your code it seems to me that the number is just `newData.length`. That being the case, display that in the HTML.

Comment: thanks, would you mind clarifying a bit more? i am still new to JavaScript, so not 100% sure what that means.

Comment: What do you mean by *"I am still new to JavaScript"*? Who wrote that code? Wasn't it you?

Comment: It was based on a bl.ocks template which i had already linked in the original posting. i was able to take the code and customize to my dataset and add a few things here and there, but that is it.

Comment: ahh was able to get it to work by setting up a div in the HTML and then adding the below code. thanks for the help!  

 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = newData.length;

Comment: i do have another question though. when the html first loads, newData.length naturally does not appear since the slider hasnt been used yet. is there a way to set the slider to start at "1" instead of "0". I know for radio buttons, you can add the tag "current" to display the one you want on load.

Comment: Just set the initial `innerHTML` of that element `result` to zero.

Answer (score 0):

ahh was able to get it to work by setting up a div in the HTML and then adding the below code. thanks for the help! document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = newData.length;